# service account execution batch dataflow job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, dataflowtask

I need to execute a dataflow job using a service account , I'm following a very simple and basic example wordcount offered within the same platform itself.

Which is weird is the error I'm getting:
[image]

According to this, GCP requires the service account having permissions as Dataflow worker in order to execute my job. The weir part comes over when the error kept on showing up even though I have already set the required permissions:

[image]

Can someone explain this strange behavior? thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

To run a Dataflow job, a project must enable billing and the following Google Cloud Platform APIs:

- Google Cloud Dataflow API
- Compute Engine API (Google Compute Engine)
- Google Cloud Logging API
- Google Cloud Storage
- Google Cloud Storage JSON API
- BigQuery API
- Google Cloud Pub/Sub
- Google Cloud Datastore API

You should also have enough quota in the  project for any one of the APIs you are using in the Dataflow job.

I would suggest you to create a fresh service account which its name has not been used before and then granting `roles/dataflow.worker` to this new fresh service account. Remember, that Cloud IAM propagation takes fewer than 60 seconds, up to 7 minutes, so please have a couple of minutes between an IAM change and Dataflow job creation.

Another possible workaround is to delete the Dataflow worker permission and add it again. The permission remains after the removal of the account, pointing to its old ID. This ID must not be refreshed until explicitly deleting the role.

I encourage you to visit [Dataflow IAM](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control#roles) roles with role descriptions and permissions documentation.